# Javascript: Determine type of Primitives when passed as params

Tags: javascript, types, parameters

Tried `typeof item.type === '<type>'` also `instanceof` none work as expected.

*Background*: I'm building a form generator (using VueJS).

This is the form definition:

```
formDesc: {
        inline: true,
        columns: 2,
        labels: 'top',
        disabled: false,
        fields: [
          {type: Array, prop: 'aprovalStatus', list: ['Pending', 'Rejected', 'Conditional', 'Approved'], label: 'Status', required: true},
          {type: String, prop: 'remarks', html: true, label: 'Remarks'},
          {type: Date, prop: 'approvalDate', label: 'Approval Date', format: 'DD-MM-YYYY'},
          {type: Number, prop: 'deposit', decimals: 2, label: 'Security Deposit'}
        ]
      }
```

The problem I'm having is determining `form.fields.<item>.type` on the form generator side. The parameter is received fine. To provide the correct input type, I need to know what the `form item` type is!

I have the following method (from one of the Google searches):

```
getType (elem) {
  return Object.prototype.toString.call(elem).slice(8, -1).toLowerCase()
}
```

Which as I read it, should return 'number', 'date' etc. 
Despite what I've read, this also returns 'function' just like `typeof item.type` does.

[Source article](http://tobyho.com/2011/01/28/checking-types-in-javascript/)

in the form generator code I have methods to determine type:

```
...
    check (item) {
      if (item && item.type) {
        console.log('getType = ', this.getType(item.type))
        return true
      } else {
        this.$message({message: 'Field item problem [' + !item ? 'Empty item' : 'no type prop for: ' + (item && item.label ? item.label : 'No label') + ']', type: 'warning'})
        return false
      }

    },

    isArray (item) {
      if (this.check(item) && this.getType(item.type) === 'array' &&
       item.hasOwnProperty('list')) {
        return true
      } else {
        return false
      }
    },
...
```

`isArray, isNumber, is Decimal` etc. are used to determine which component to show for each element in `formDesc.fields`.

My other attempts were `item.type.constructor === Number`

Any links or solutions for this greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Silly me. This works `item.type === Number` (or relevant primitive data type)